# How to configure VS Code's "tasks.json" to build all .ts files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Its possible this has been asked before if so I am sorry for the duplicate post simply redirect me to the other thread.

Is it possible to configure VS Code's **"tasks.json"** to **compile all .ts files in the folder**. I know I can add the path to the .ts file manually like this:

```
"args": [ HelloWorld.ts ],
```

and it does compile the HelloWorld.ts correctly but I cannot figure out how to setup the tasks.json that all.ts files in the folder are compiled.

I have looked at some tutorials which all suggest to simply remove the "HelloWorld.ts" but that does not work as no .ts files are compiled at all.

Here is the entire tasks.json file that I have in VS Code:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "always",

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    "args": [ "HelloWorld.ts" ],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have my full project environment with me, but I know I was able to accomplish this with a "tsconfig.json" file and pointing TSC to just the folder containing it, with the argument "-p". VS Code might be able to help you fill in the various options for tsconfig.json.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @mishap said but what his answer was missing was that there should be an empty space for the "args" like so:

```
"args": [ ]
```

rather than:

```
"args": []
```

As those args are passed to the cmd/terminal executing the **tsc** it is important that there is a space " " in the "args" of the tasks.json.

Answer (score 4):

In your tasks.json remove content of squared brackets for "args" key:

```
"args": []
```

Make sure you do have tsconfig.json file in place too.
This successfully compiles all .ts files for me.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe a bit of overkill for your task but for my project I use gulp and its nicely supported by VSCode.

First you should setup tsconfig.json for your project, where you will be able to exclude unnecessary files. I find it easier to exclude what you do not need than to include whats needed. This is especially true for large projects.

```
{ 
     "compilerOptions": { 
         "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, 
         "experimentalDecorators": true,
         "module": "commonjs", 
         "target": "es5",
         "sourceMap": true,
         "outDir": "dist",
         "declaration": true
     },
     "exclude": [
         "node_modules",
         "dist",
         ".vscode",
         "docs"
     ]
}
```

This is how your tasks.json might look like:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "node",
    "windows": {
        "command": "node.exe"
    },
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build-debug",
            "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js", "build-debug"],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that I used here local installation of gulp.

And here is sample gulpfile.js:

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var merge = require('merge2');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var del = require('del');

var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('build-debug', function() {
    del.sync("dist");

    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())   
    .pipe(ts(tsProject));

    return merge([
        //Build typescript to dist folder 
        // tsResult.dts
        //     .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')),
        tsResult.js
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./", { sourceRoot: __dirname }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')),
});
```

And do not forget to add corresponding dev dependencies to your package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "latest",
    "gulp-typescript": "latest",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "latest",
    "merge2": "latest",
    "del": "latest"
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the args altogether this worked for me.

```
"args": ["-p", "${workspaceRoot}"]
```

There are a bunch of pre-defined variables you can used that will be replaced at runtime. This this page for more information: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive? Pasting a row of code is not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Make a _all.ts file , add references of all the files you want to compile and pass it to the args parameter.

It will output a single file containing all the transpiled code.

I hope this helps

Comment: Indeed this would "do" the trick of compiling all of the ts code to js code but it will force me after that to reference a single .js file in my html which would kind of kill the idea of "separation of concern".

Answer (score 0):

```
--==========================
  - VS Code - Setup TypeScript Compiler 
  - source : https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript
--==========================
1/ create a file "tsconfig.json"

        {
            "compilerOptions": {
                "target": "es5",
                "module": "commonjs",
                "sourceMap": true
            }
        }

2/ Create tasks.json : 
    - Ctrl+Shift+P ==> Configure Task Runner
    - Select TypeScript - tsconfig.json.
    {
        // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
        // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "command": "tsc",
        "isShellCommand": true,
        "args": ["-p", "."],
        "showOutput": "silent",
        "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
    }

3/ Run the Build Task : Ctrl+Shift+B (Run Build Task)
```